# MySQL query with 2 queries on same table to match exactly same values

Tags: mysql, group-by, count, distinct, exact-match

I have a table with 2 fields, name and number. I need to get the names which contains all the numbers matching exactly in a list.
For eg.

table `details`

```
----------
name | number
----------
A    |   1    
A    |   2    
B    |   1    
C    |   1
D    |   1    
D    |   2   
D    |   3
```

if my list is `(1,2)` , output should be `A` only
if my list is `(1,2,3)` , output should be `D` only
if my list is `(1)` , output should be  `B,C`

This is what I tried

```
SELECT name FROM details 
WHERE number IN (1,2) 
GROUP BY name 
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT number)=2
```

Comment: Is haiving a transcription error or is that what you have in your query?

Comment: @P.Salmon where?

Comment: Last line of your code.

Comment: sorry.. mistake while posting question..thats not the issue here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something to think about:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(name CHAR(1) NOT NULL
,number INT NOT NULL
,PRIMARY KEY(name,number)
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
('A',1),
('A',2),
('B',1),
('C',1),
('D',1),
('D',2),
('D',3);

SELECT *, number IN (1,2) x FROM my_table;
+------+--------+---+
| name | number | x |
+------+--------+---+
| A    |      1 | 1 |
| A    |      2 | 1 |
| B    |      1 | 1 |
| C    |      1 | 1 |
| D    |      1 | 1 |
| D    |      2 | 1 |
| D    |      3 | 0 |
+------+--------+---+

SELECT name
     , COUNT(*)
     , SUM(number IN (1,2)) x 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY name;
+------+----------+------+
| name | COUNT(*) | x    |
+------+----------+------+
| A    |        2 |    2 |
| B    |        1 |    1 |
| C    |        1 |    1 |
| D    |        3 |    2 |
+------+----------+------+
```

...and just in case it needs spelling out...

```
SELECT name
  FROM my_table
 GROUP
    BY name
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2 -- DISTINCT is redundant because of my PRIMARY KEY
   AND COUNT(*) = SUM(number IN (1,2));
;
+------+
| name |
+------+
| A    |
+------+
```

Comment: It *always* needs spelling out! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try using `group_concat`

```
SELECT 
    name
FROM
    (SELECT 
        name, GROUP_CONCAT(number) AS gr
    FROM
        details
    GROUP BY name) a
WHERE
    gr = '1,2';
```

Comment: You cannot rely on the notion of a 'natural' order.